# Magento Export/Import billing_vat

Tags: magento-1.9, import, csv, export, dataflow

When I use dataflow profiles to export customers the exported CSV-file does not contain the customers billing_vat field. I only get the taxvat field.

I believe I have to modify the parser to include the vat field, but how and where to I change this?

I've copied:

> app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Conver/Parser/Customer.php

To local.

Comment: I have The simil problem.
I can not to import The Field billing_vat_id Why? I See the field in backend and frontend But i can not to export. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

You have to modify **app/code/core/Mage/Customer/etc/config.xml** and to add in node `<customer_dataflow>` this:

```
        <vat_id>
            <billing>1</billing>
            <shipping>1</shipping>
        </vat_id>
```

or you can add this in your own module.